# Take an array and add a value to each item?

Tags: swift

Not sure if I worded that right, anyway I have an array with integers.

I need to add/multiply/divide/subtract a value from every item in the array.

So like this:

start with

```
var listOfInts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and add 3 to every item, resulting in

```
listOfInts = [4,5,6,8,9]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been frustrating since I normally can figure out these things by myself but I'm relatively new to Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to mutate your array instead of creating a new one (like `map` does), just use a `for` loop to walk through and change the value at each index:

```
var listOfInts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]   

for i in 0 ..< listOfInts.count {
    listOfInts[i] += 3
}

print(listOfInts)  // prints "[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
```

---

This can be written as a one-liner like this:

```
(0 ..< listOfInts.count).forEach { listOfInts[$0] += 3 }
```

---

If you need to do something more with the value, you can use `enumerate()` to access a series of `(index, value)` tuples:

```
// Example:  Replace each element with 60/value
listOfInts.enumerate().forEach { (i, v) in listOfInts[i] = 60 / v }

// This is the equivalent using a for loop
for (i, v) in listOfInts.enumerate() {
    listOfInts[i] = 60 / v
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 8):

Map to new array:
`var newListOfInts = listOfInts.map({ $0 + 3 })`

Mutate same array: `listOfInts = listOfInts.map({ $0 + 3 })`